# linkedlist, cannot link the node to head

Tags: c++, linked-list

I just lost the direction in the middle of somewhere, I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. A functions below is my append function to put node into list.

```
void AppendNode(struct s_list *list, unsigned int data)
{
    if (list == nullptr)
        return;

    struct s_node *tempHead = list->head;
    struct s_node *newNode = new s_node;
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    while (tempHead != nullptr)
        tempHead = tempHead->next;

    tempHead = newNode;
}
```

I'm calling this function 100 times and it won't link the new node with current list at all. It shouldn't be hard to find the problem but I'm so bad. Give me some advice. Thanks.

//*************************************************************************//

Thanks for all reply but I still have a same problem. I already allocate the head node for my list then pass it to the function. Now, I changed to pass head of list directly, not list anymore but still have a same issue...

```
void AppendNode(struct s_node *head, unsigned int data)
{
    if (head == nullptr)
        return;

    struct s_node *tempHead = head;
    struct s_node *newNode = new s_node;
    newNode->next = nullptr;

    while (tempHead != nullptr)
        tempHead = tempHead->next;

    tempHead = newNode;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `tempHead` runs right off the end of the list; nothing in this function changes the list.

First deal with the case of an empty list:

```
if(list->head == NULL)
{
  list->head = newNode;
  return;
}
```

Then advance with caution:

```
while (tempHead->next != nullptr)
  tempHead = tempHead->next;

tempHead->next = newNode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you are trying to append the node to the end of list, just do:

```
while (tempHead->next != nullptr)
    tempHead = tempHead->next;

tempHead->next = newNode;
```

Comment: @user58569 my bad, you should change the first line to use tempHead->next != nullptr instead of tempHead != nullptr

Comment: I really in panic because what in my head is correct, I can follow your comment, but it doesn't work..... really weird and makes me feel so bad. When I watch my head pointer through debug screen, head keep failing to get new node as its next one.

Comment: So in the second post of your code, in addition to the advance code change, you have to add the new node even in the-list-is-empty case:
`if (head == nullptr) head = newNode; return;`
Let me know if this works.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. When I check the head pointer through debug screen, it shows me head has its memory address (which means it's allocated) but its next node is still null after I put newNode as head's next. Something must be wrong but I'm so blind...